# The average of a subharmonic function on a circle increases with radius

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions, potential-theory, monotone-functions

> Let $u$ be a subharmonic on open set $\Omega$. Let $a\in\Omega,R>0$ such that $B(a,r)\subset \Omega$. Prove $$v(\rho)=\int_0^{2\pi}u(a+\rho e^{it})dt$$ is a monotone increasing function on $(0,R)$.

For a sub harmonic function we know that $u(a)\le v(\rho)$ for any value of $\rho<R$. I thought maybe using Harnack's inequality but I don't know how.

How can we use the fact that $u$ is sub harmonic to prove monotonicity of the integral?

Answer (score 2):

A couple of approaches:

#### Majorization

Let $h$ be a harmonic function in $B(a,r)$ such that $h=u$ on $\partial B(a,r)$. Then $u\le h$ in $B(a,r)$ (hence the name, **sub**-harmonic). For harmonic functions, averages on concentric circles are the same. Hence, the average of $u$ on $\partial B(a,s)$ for $s<r$ does not exceed its average on $\partial B(a,r)$.

#### Differentiation

Assume $u$ is smooth for now. Differentiate its average on $\partial B(a,r)$ with respect to $r$. This gives the integral of normal derivative of $u$, which is the flux of the gradient $\nabla u$ out of the disk. By the divergence theorem, this flux is equal to the integral of Laplacian over the disk, which is nonnegative.  This proves monotonicity for smooth subharmonic functions.

The general case is then handled by approximation: every subharmonic function is the decreasing limit of smooth subharmonic functions, namely its mollifications.

Comment: Thanks. I understood the Differentiation approach but about the first approach: why  the average of $v$ on ∂B(a,s) for s<r does not exceed its average on ∂B(a,r)? How that follows ?

Comment: Average of $v$ is $\le $ average of $h$, which is the same on both circles.

Comment: so $v(s)=\int_0^{2\pi} u(a+se^{it})dt\le\int_0^{2\pi}h(a+se^{it})dt=\int_0^{2\pi}h(a+re^{it})dt$ but from where get $\le v(r)$?

Comment: On the circle of radius $r$, the two functions are equal.

Comment: So did you mean to choose $h$ harmonic such that $h\equiv u$ rather than v on $\partial B(a,r)$?

Comment: Yes, $v$ was meant to be $u$. Corrected.

Comment: But, following the majorization approach, how do we know a harmonic function with the prescribed values in the border exists?